# Serialize objects like Google Gson but into compact binary format?

Tags: java, serialization

I'm hoping there is a library that allows serialization of Java POJOs, in a similar manner to Google's excellent Gson library.

However, I need the serialized format to be extremely compact (they need to fit into individual UDP packets), and so I'm concerned that serializing to JSON would be wasteful, and would prefer a binary format.

Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some days ago I found [BSON](http://www.bsonspec.org) which claims to be a simple binary representation of JSON. I did not try this, but from its FAQ, it is not always more compact than JSON (small numbers use more space), but easier (quicker) to parse and produce. If you have known data types to transmit, other protocols could be more efficient (in terms of space, at least) than this.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Hessian](http://hessian.caucho.com/) instead. If you want to save some more space, decorate its stream with [GZipOutput/Input Stream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html)

Comment: The problem with compression is that each message must be compressed individually.  As UDP is lossy and session less, you don't know when a stream starts or has something missing making compressing over multiple packets impractical.

Comment: You would have to use a new Stream for each packet. But often such general-purpose compression algorithms are better for larger amounts of data - you would have to benchmark if it gives anything.

Comment: Perhaps a good idea would be to use Hessian build in compression and message signaturing (if needed).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the default serialization format? It's binary, but not cross-language.

Maybe gzipped JSON could work.

Or you could look into [protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of protocol buffers, but has anyone created an implementation of it that serializes POJOs in the same way that Google Gson does?